# Eclipse debug android project not show complete stack trace?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I am writing some simple Android project with Eclipse IDE. 
I have some trouble with the Debug mode. This is my code:

```
package com.test.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //playMusicFromWeb();
        forceError();

    }
    private void forceError(){
        if (true)
            throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I debuging the project (Project Right CLick -> Debug As -> Android Application), the debug display only 2 first method call, and it doesn't show what is the "deepest" method that throw an exception:
[image]

I insert a breakpoint to the `onCreate` method, at statement `forceError();`. Then debug again, the stack trace show correctly as I want, but when I click `Resume`, the debug still show a few information like above.

in my ebook that I am reading, the debug show all method that in the stack trace exception:
[image]

So, my question is: How to show the complete stack trace by the Debug, without set any breakpoint manually?

Comment: the stacktrace is logged in the logcat console, regardless of debugging.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to know that why the debug screenshot in my ebook show all the stack trace?

Comment: My ebook is: "Introduction to Android Application Development, 4th Edition", page 82

Comment: your debug session does not appear to be linked with the source of the project. That can come from many things. (if you are learning android, though, I would recommend dumping Eclipse and start using Android Studio)